# How to store chains of information?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am currently trying to design a table structure that can capture report data (from various sources) in an ordered fashion.

Let me give you an example:

Each day I receive three separate reports from various companies (one report per company). These reports are a dump of their database tables and include `PK`, `FK to previous report row (of another company)`, `Amount`, `CustomerID`, `Timestamp` and some other unrelated fields.

The order of the reports is very important. The three reports create a chain that I am interested in (query later). Each record only knows about its immediate predecessor (`FK to previous report row`) and is `NULL` if it is the root record.

The problem I am running into is the fact that for certain chains, the length of the chain can be 5 reports, others are 3. I'm wondering if it is possible to design a Chain(?) definition table somehow and reference a chain id somewhere in the record so that the record knows which part of the chain it belongs to.

The previous developer created a table **per** report and had humongous amounts of business logic to tie report chains together. I would like to abstract this design so that the tables are agnostic to the reports and have one to four tables instead of *fourty-seven*.

Once everything is stored, I would like to query a specific master record and see all children records and their amounts.

I read about self referencing tables, but I am not quite sure if this is the right way to go.

SQL: `SQL Server 2008R2`

Comment: Look into recursive CTEs.  Look at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/162685/proper-data-structure-for-commentable-comments/162695#162695 for more info.

Comment: Thanks Max. I used a self reference as suggested by mrdenny. The link you provided has a similar issue and was solved in the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you've described a self referencing table is the way to go.  This only works if you can get all the data into a single schema (which you probably can).  It'll make the management a piece of cake and you can have changes on infinite length at this point.